# Detect when AJAX request is accessing a different IE security zone from origin

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there any way to determine programmatically, in the browser via JS, whether an AJAX request to a cross-origin domain is dropping cookies in IE because of Protected Mode state isolation between security zones?

It would be nice to show the user a warning in this case rather than a silent failure.

CORS is otherwise allowed via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and cookies are enabled via `withCredentials`, so I'm focused on the state-sharing problem unique to IE.  Chrome is working fine.

Comment: An ajax request to another origin won't allow cookies to be sent or set unless `withCredentials` is set in the request

Comment: clarified that is not the issue; also, Chrome does not have the same issue

Comment: Not really clear what the issue is then